# How to run code.org animations offline using javascript and html files?

Tags: javascript, animation, sprite, draw, code.org

I'm trying to run the following script from a code.org GameLab studio offline using .js and html files.

```
var blueGear = createSprite(100, 200);
blueGear.setAnimation("blue_gear");

blueGear.Scale = 1;

var greenGear = createSprite(250, 278);
greenGear.setAnimation("green_gear");

greenGear.scale = 2;

var redGear = createSprite(85, 110);
redGear.setAnimation("red_gear");

redGear.scale = 0.75;

var sameRotationRate = 3;

function draw() {
  background("white");
  //1) Make the gears rotate so they look like they are working as one system
  
  blueGear.rotation = blueGear.rotation - sameRotationRate;
  greenGear.rotation = greenGear.rotation + sameRotationRate;
  redGear.rotation = redGear.rotation + sameRotationRate;
  
  
  drawSprites();
}
```

The files for the individual gears and a sample of the resulting animation(ignoring scaling and position in the code) are shown below.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Now, inorder to run this animations offline, I followed some ChatGPT suggestions did the following:

1. Downloaded the [p5.js](https://p5js.org/download/) and [p5.play](https://github.com/molleindustria/p5.play) and library files following ChatGPT suggestions.
2. Created index.html and gears.js as follows:

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   Include p5.js from the local directory
  <script src="p5.js"></script>
  <script src="planck.min.js"></script>
  <script src="p5.play.js"></script>
  <title>Gear Animation</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="gears.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

> gears.js

```
// Create Gears
let blueGear, greenGear, redGear;
const sameRotationRate = 3;

function setup() {
  
  console.log("Setup function is called.");
  createCanvas(400, 400);

  // Initialize Blue Gear
  blueGear = createSprite(100, 200);
  blueGear.addAnimation("default", "blue_gear.png"); // Replace "blue_gear.png" with the actual file name
  blueGear.scale = 1;

  // Initialize Green Gear
  greenGear = createSprite(250, 278);
  greenGear.addAnimation("default", "green_gear.png"); // Replace "green_gear.png" with the actual file name
  greenGear.scale = 2;

  // Initialize Red Gear
  redGear = createSprite(85, 110);
  redGear.addAnimation("default", "red_gear.png"); // Replace "red_gear.png" with the actual file name
  redGear.scale = 0.75;
}

function draw() {

  console.log("Draw function is called.");
  background("white");

  // Rotate Gears
  blueGear.rotation -= sameRotationRate;
  greenGear.rotation += sameRotationRate;
  redGear.rotation += sameRotationRate;

  drawSprites();
}
```

This leads to a bunch of errors and there was no end to it. Even if I manage to use basic javascript with inbuilt animations object, I only get an empty screen when I open the HTML file in the browser.

Am I missing something in the way i'm linking the p5 libraries? Has anyone tried this and have a cheatsheet of steps for running code.org animations offline?